# PCI-E Card cards caused ethernet goes off

Tags: linux, motherboard, ethernet, pci-express

I have a problem, with the PCI-E. 
If i plug any kind of PCI-E cards to the motherboard, the ethernet goes off, but the card is working.
System: Ubuntu 18.04 What can be the problem?
(I tested with: Gigabit Ethernet card, SATA Raid card, USB card.)

Comment: Is the problem slot dependent?  Do you have multiple PCI-E slots, and if so if you plug a card into any of them does it disable your network?  Have you checked for a BIOS update?  Checked the settings in the BIOS?  Whats your kernel version?  less than 4.19, probably look into updating it.

Comment: Sounds like a motherboard problem. Linux shouldn't care what you plug in